# Probability of equality between two discrete random variables

Tags: probability

Let $X \sim Po(\lambda)$ and $P(Y=k)=\frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)},k \ge 0$. Find $P(X=Y)$.

My attempt: Assuming that *X* and *Y* are independent, we have $$P(X=Y)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}P(X=k) \cdot P(Y=k)$$ $$=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda^k e^{- \lambda}}{(k+2)!}$$

The only other piece of information provided was that the answer involved a sum. Am I on the right track?

Comment: ...That is, *assuming X and Y are independent* (otherwise this cannot be solved).

Comment: The question didn't mention it so I'm assuming independence.

Comment: Then mention this (crucial) hypothesis in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just continuing on from what you did, 
$$P(X=Y) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^ke^{-\lambda}}{(k+2)!}=\frac{1}{\lambda^2}\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{\lambda^ke^{-\lambda}}{k!}=\frac{1}{\lambda^2}\cdot\left(1-e^{-\lambda}-\lambda e^{-\lambda}\right)$$
where we used the fact that $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^ke^{-\lambda}}{k!}=1\implies \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{\lambda^ke^{-\lambda}}{k!}=1-e^{-\lambda}-\lambda e^{-\lambda}$$